# Way for ResultSet FORWARD_ONLY count rows

Tags: java, postgresql, resultset

I use PostgresSQl database and faced a problem where I have to count rows, using FORWARD_ONLY ResultSet. Also, I use JDBCTemplate, that prepares sql request and execute it under the hood. So, there is no way to create two-way cursor.

```
private void doGetData(String sql, MapSqlParameterSource params, Consumer<Map<String, Object>> consumer) {
   transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Object>() {             
      @Override             
      public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) { 
         return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, rs -> {   

            //should count rows here

            long rowCount = 0;                     
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();                     
            Map<String, Object> row = new LinkedHashMap<>();  
            while (rs.next()) {     
               for (int i = 1; i < metaData.getColumnCount() + 1; i++) { 
                  row.put(metaData.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i)); 
               }                         
               consumer.accept(row);                        
               rowCount++;                                    
                         }                
                  if(rowCount == 0) {   
               throw new NoContentException(); 
            }    
            return rowCount;      
        });  
     }         
});
```

I tried to make cursor become two-way somehow, but it seems impossible cause of realization. The last idea I got, is to use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM *sql*`

But I think it will produce less performance.

If you have any ideas, it will really help me.

Comment: That depends on the number of rows right now, amd the expected increase in the future. If it's not gonna be that much, using a plain count is the more productive, readable and mantainable way. And scalable but in the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You have only two options:

1. Run the query as you do now and just increment a counter. At the end you now know how many rows you had.
2. If you need the info at the beginning, then one way or another the database is going to have to inefficiently run the query twice in a row, which, in the case of postgres is slow (because it is just - a sufficiently complicated query results in a complex answer that can take a while to compute if the appropriate indices aren't available). Might as well run the `SELECT COUNT(*)` query, and know that it costs a bit.

Your code snippet does the first thing but does it incorrectly. You do a check on if the rowCount is 0 **inside** the while loop. You want it outside, afterwards.